# How to include code into the current file from an external file in compile time?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a project which will be used as a template. I'll then copy it and create a sub-project based on it. I want to be able to update it from the upstream.

All the `*.ex` files that are specific to a sub-project won't be in git. Therefore, they'll have to be created manually and loaded dynamically.

Question: how to load external `.ex` into the current, to then compile it? Not at runtime, but at the compile-time.

This will be something similar to this:

```elixir
# my_controller.ex
defmodule MyAppWeb.MyController do
  use MyAppWeb, :controller

  def page1(conn, params) do
    # ........
  end



  # HOW to implement this function?
  inject_external_file_if_exists("my_controller.personal.ex")
end
```

Code specific to a sub-project could look like this:

```elixir
# my_controller.personal.ex
defmodule MyAppWeb.MyController do
  use MyAppWeb, :controller

  def specific_page1(conn, params) do
    # ........
  end


  def specific_page2(conn, params) do
    # ........
  end
end
```

Note that `my_controller.personal.ex` contains the definition of `MyAppWeb.MyController` once again. This isn't a strict requirement. The idea is **to merge at compile** them rather than overwrite each other.

Comment: Which project is the one actually getting run? I know "don't do this" answers are what this site is infamous for, but merging modules is tricky (some workarounds here: https://elixirforum.com/t/adding-modifying-module-functions-in-a-previous-livebook-cell/50307), and there may be a better way of doing what you're trying to do. Why is the modules having the same name a "strict requirement"? If I wanted to do something like this I would probably lean more towards having the template be a dependency of the other, defining a macro instead of a module containing shared code.

Comment: @BrettBeatty “do not do this” is the perfectly valid answer when you see an attempt to produce a template engine coming from a person barely understanding what [tag:elixir] code injection is in a nutshell.

Comment: @BrettBeatty  "Why does a module have the same name a "strict requirement"?" -->  typo. "Not strict". Even still, why would I name them differently? The question is how, rather than "why".

Comment: Dynamically injecting code at compile time (generally) seems like a "too clever for its own good" type of solution.  Reminds me of other tricks I've seen over the years like self-modifying code and some of the stuff in the obfuscated C contest.  I'd really think long and hard if there's not some less tricky way to do what you need to do.